# Getting large AJAX responses in Chrome without crashing

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working on a project which is aimed at the Chrome browser.  Our goal which we would like to accomplish is to get a one million record array into the browser to work with the data.  When I generated a test file that contained a million records it was a bit more than one gigabyte.

For reasons I will explain, I believe we can accomplish the goal if can get the browser to collect the garbage when necessary.  I believe the browser holds the text of the AJAX responses when it doesn't need to and crashes for that reason.

Now, I can generate a million records within the browser and manipulate it as I need to.  However, I have trouble sending the AJAX to the browser without crashing it.

Since sending one million crashes it, I tried sending batches of one hundred thousand.  I can get two such batches across and parse the JSON.  If I do not have a onreadystatechange on my AJAX call, I can make the call a number of times.  Also, if I receive a hundred thousand records, I can go over it ten times and make the full array.

Because I seem to be able to actually hold one million records, I believe that, as I said, holding the response texts is overwhelming the browsers.

In order to try to get better memory management, I have pushed the AJAX resquests and parsing into a web worker.  When the webworker gets the AJAX and makes the hundred thousand record array, it pushes it to the DOM thread.  When the DOM thread has taken the data it has the web worker do another AJAX.

However, it still crashes.

I am open to using websockets or something else, if that would help somehow.

Here is the code in the DOM thread:

```
var iterations=3;
var url='hunthou.json';      
var worker=new Worker('src/worker.js');
var count=0;
    worker.addEventListener('message',function(e){
      alert('count: '+count);
      //bigArr=bigArr.concat(e.data);
      console.log('e.data length: '+e.data.length);
      bigArr[count]=e.data;
      console.log('bigArr length: '+bigArr.length);
      if(count<(iterations-1)){
        worker.postMessage(url);  
      } else{
        alert('done');
        console.log('done');
        worker.terminate();
        console.log('bye');
      }
      count++;
    });
worker.postMessage(url);
```

Here is the webworker:

```
var arr=[];
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
    if (this.readyState === DONE){          
        arr=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
        self.postMessage(arr);          
        arr.length=0;
        request.responseText.length=0;
        console.log('okay');
    }
};

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    var url=e.data;
    console.log('url: '+url);

    request.open("GET",'../'+url,true);
    request.send(null);
}, false);
```

Comment: 1 million records in the browser sent in one ajax request?  Is that really the only and best way to design this?  You're going to have at least two copies of the data just because of `JSON.parse()` and maybe serious garbage collection issues during the running of that huge a `JSON.parse()` operation, not to mention data copies that may be made when passing between threads.  Multiple copies of data are probably at least part of the issue.

Comment: The user's memory will simply not be able to hold that many records, no matter how you pull them. This is bad app structure, not a problem with memory-leaks or ajax.

Comment: @jfriend00 I specifically said I split it over multiple requests.

Comment: @JamesG. I specifically said that I have determined that the browser does hold that number of records and allows for the manipulation of data.  If you have the browser generate the records there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the whole data at once.

You can create multiple requests which will retrieve chunks of data instead of retrieving whole data at once, this will prevent your browser from crashing.